# ql_illegal_argument_exception during data fetch from ELK using Spring Boot REST API

Tags: spring-boot, rest, elk

I am using a sql query to fetch data from ELK. Few fields return array of values.

SQL Query:

```
select * from index1 order by timestamp desc limit 3.
```

The response generated using Kibana is ,

```
{'took': 1, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0
    }, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 84, 'relation': 'eq'
        }, 'max_score': None, 'hits': [
            {'_index': 'index1', '_id': 'wkfhsdufnd', '_score': None, '_source': {'timestamp': '2023-10-16 10: 58: 26.348779',  
            'top3Errors': ['java.lang.Throwable: SNA : {Status=9999, Service=login
                        }', 'java.lang.Throwable: SNA : {Status=9009, Service=getDetails
                        }', 'java.lang.Throwable: SNA : {Status=9999, Service=getDetails
                        }'
                    ]
                }, 'sort': [
                    1697453906348
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

The Rest API that is used to fetch the above data throws the following error,

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"ql_illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Arrays (returned by [top3Errors]) are not supported"}],"type":"ql_illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Arrays (returned by [top3Errors]) are not supported"},"status":500}

The data type of the field 'top3Errors' is TEXT in the ELK index1.

How to handle the array values returned from the ELK in the spring boot application?